# Switching between projects in Aptana 3

Tags: ide, workspace

I have two large projects. Each project has a bunch of files, that should be opened in Aptana.

When i close project A and open project B, i need to close a bunch of files from project A and to reopen files for project B.

Is there a way to create a kind of workspace for each project to avoid reopening and rearranging panels for each project ?

Answer (score 1):

For panels, create a new perspective under `Window>Save Perspective As...`

For opening folders, use Working Sets to your advantage.